# Is there a way to add to OS X's install.log from within a shell script?

Tags: macos, logging, installation

Is there a way to add an entry to OS X's /var/log/install.log file from within a shell script?

Optimally the method wouldn't require root access as I don't think I'll have it.

The problem I'm having is I'm executing a shell script as part of an **installation-check** (p15 of Apple's [Distribution Definition XML Schema](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/DistributionDefinitionRef.pdf)) step from within an OS X installer package via the Javascript **System.run**() command (p30 of Apple's [Installer Javascript Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/InstallerJavaScriptRef/InstallerJavaScriptRef.pdf)), but I can't see any output from that shell script.

I know the shell script is executing, because when I use the "logger" command from within the script, my log text appears inside /var/log/system.log.  But in order to get a complete picture of what's going on, I'd need to merge it by hand with /var/log/install.log, which is where the general output of the installer, and any Javascript logging I do, ends up.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried using the "logger" command's -f flag to use /var/log/install.log, e.g.

```
logger -f /var/log/install.log sometext
```

...but no dice; sometext still gets added to /var/log/system.log.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm in a very similar scenario (bash/pyhthon pre/post build scripts that need logging). Installer Man page(8) does talk of an "LOG_INSTALL facility" but I wasn't able to understand what it is, and whether my scripts can use it.

Comment: @MottiShneor I haven't, but I am still curious.. let me know if you figure anything out. I'm sorry it's taken so long to reply, only just saw your comment today.  I might take another look, since it's been 3+ years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late, but just had the same problem and was able to add logs to *install.log* from AppleScript using *[logger](https://man.openbsd.org/logger.1)* with the *LOG_INSTALL* facility:

```
logger -p 'install.error' "My error message"
```

Comment: This works. Log includes the username running the `logger` command as well as the PID

Comment: I've long since lost the development environment I was using since I wrote my question, but I can confirm in 2023 (macOS Ventura 13.2.1) that this works! Thank you, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

OK. Long time passed, and I found out the following.

In normal scenarios, anything written by pre and post install scripts (mine are python and bash) to stdout will be logged by the installer daemon to the /var/log/install.log. I experimented various tools to create my installer packages, and they usually did this.

However, in my own deployment installer, for some reason, only things written to stderr get logged to the /var/log/install.log - so you might want to try that too.

Comment: Hey, cool, thanks for looking into it again. I will give it a try and report back here how it goes

Comment: It works in our product... after you test it, and If you find it worthy, vote!

Comment: This works! MacOS Big Sur

Answer (score 1):

That's not an answer per se, but maybe a hint? Installer man pages mention a "LOG_INSTALL facility", whose output is the desired /var/log/install.log

But what is this "facility" and where is it available - I can't find. I really need to write my pre/post script failures and specific scenarios to that log.